# How to declare array of N elements of custom type in Typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have created my own type called tuple, and I want to make an array, of length 10, with elements of type tuple. How do I do that (possibly) with that specific Array syntax, or any other?

```
type tuple =  [number, number]

var numbers: Array<tuple> = []
```

Comment: Make it a tuple of tuples?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your posted code. Do you mean that you want a type that is a tuple of 10 of the `[number, number]` tuple type? Or do you want to create a `tuple[]` array at runtime with 10 items in it? Which part there are you having trouble with? Please [edit] your question and add some information about your desired result.

Comment: Sorry for bad explaining. Desired outcome is to have an array of length 10, where every item is of type tuple, so I could just ,for example, in very next line say numbers[3] = [3,15]; without actually having to push items first to get 3rd spot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it a tuple of tuples? Or specifically, a tuple of the type `tuple` you already have.

```
type tuple =  [number, number];

const numbers: [tuple, tuple, tuple, tuple, ...] = [...];
```

Comment: Actually haven't thought about it. But this could be hard if I want higher array lengths. Of course I could push empty elements, but was hoping for neat solution

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a separate answer if you're okay with having default values for your `tuple`, something like this could work:

```
type tuple = [number, number]
type TupleArray<tuple, TupleLen extends number> = [tuple, ...tuple[]] & { length: TupleLen }

let numbers: TupleArray<tuple, 10> = Array(10).fill([0, 0]) as TupleArray<tuple, 10>;
```

With this approach, you're specifically typing `TupleArray` to have a specific length, so there is the added caveat of an empty array or any array above or below a length of 10 would throw an error. This is also why you need to fill your array with  10 `tuple`s.